# ArgumentCaptor is ignoring class type

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm using an ArgumentCaptor in a test, but the class passed into the argument capture is different from the class that is actually being captured. The behavior is very inconsistent, on some machines it will throw an exception (which I would expect it to do), and on others it simply captures the object and continues.

Here's an example, where ClassOne is being passed into the ArgumentCaptor, but an instance of ClassTwo is being captured. ClassOne and ClassTwo are completely independent, nothing is extending the other:

```
ClassTwo expected = ClassTwo.builder().build();
ArgumentCaptor<ClassOne> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ClassOne.class);
verify(subject).send(argumentCaptor.capture());
assertThat(captor.getValue()).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expected);
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? And even more, why do we get different behavior between different machines?

Comment: Can you show the signature of `subject#send`?

Comment: It takes in a single Object, which might explain why it can capture another class, but I'm still not sure why it's not consistent between machines.

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not consistent"?

Comment: You need to describe the behaviour you are seeing in more detail, and show the code which calls `send`. You can also put a breakpoint on the call to `send` to see why it is being called with a value you don't expect.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no type check in the `ArgumentCaptor`:

> This utility class *don't do any type checks*, the generic signatures are only there to avoid casting in your code.

**Source:** https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html